# PHP String Parsing

Tags: php, regex

I have string which contains something about `"amount 3 val 6, amount 7 val 8"` and so, what regular expression should I use to get array with corresponding amounts and values?

Comment: Is there ever a case where you wouldn't have a value for something?  For instance "amount val 5, amount 8 val 4, amount 6 val"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "amount 3 val 6, amount 7 val 8";
preg_match_all('~amount (\d+) val (\d+)~i', $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'amount 3 val 6, amount 7 val 8';
preg_match_all('#amount\s+(\d+)\s+val\s+(\d+)#', $str, $matches);
```

All amounts in $matches[1], all vals in $matches[2].

Answer (score 0):

```
amount\s*(\d*)\s*val\s*(\d*)
```

You can do the rest